# How does HIV bestow 'double meaning' to Blood Diamond?

Tags: blood-diamond

In response to a fan theory that Danny Archer (portrayed by Leonardo DiCaprio) in the 2006 movie *Blood Diamond* had HIV, [this Reddit comment](https://old.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/1dopxt/danny_archer_leonardo_dicaprio_in_blood_diamond/c9sf1pk/) quips

> Nice double meaning to the movie's title as well.

I don't understand how HIV would yield this double meaning? I know that [HIV can be transmitted by blood](https://www.avert.org/hiv-transmission-prevention/myths), but how does HIV  relate to diamonds? The HIV virus doesn't look like diamonds?

Comment: It could be a figurative diamond, referring to just one trait you can say a diamond has, like rarity. IMHO you're overthinking a 'smartass' Reddit comment. I wouldn't think about them too much, be it 1 upvote or 10000.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who said it what they mean rather than asking us to speculate on what they might have meant?

Answer (score 4):

If true (because I haven't seen the movie), I think perhaps it's more that the double meaning is in the context of the word "blood" more than diamond, with diamond being a filler word on "value".

**[Interview](https://emanuellevy.com/interviews/blood-diamond-ed-zwick-7/) with Director Ed Zwick:**

> What’s Valuable in Life
>
> **To me, this movie is about what is valuable**, says director-producer
>   Edward Zwick. To one person, it might be a stone; to someone else, a
>   story in a magazine; to another, it is a child. **The juxtaposition of
>   one man obsessed with finding a valuable diamond** with another man
>   risking his life to find his son is the beating heart of this film.
>
> Meaning of Diamonds
>
> In the African country of Sierra Leone, where many of the worlds
>   diamonds are mined, they have taken on a much darker connotation.
>   Zwick explains, Conflict diamonds are stones that have been smuggled
>   out of countries at war. They then go to pay for more arms, **increasing
>   the death toll and furthering the destruction of the region**. They may
>   be a small percentage of the worlds sales, but, nonetheless, in an
>   industry worth billions of dollars, even a small percentage is worth
>   many millions and can buy innumerable small arms.

So the character whose motivated or *fighting for* certain kinds of diamonds, that primarily exist in "war zones", is also internally fighting against HIV, which destroys the white blood cells that are used to fight off infections, which can then lead to death.

It's the idea that being obsessed with 'blood diamonds' parallels the notion of a virus destroying the body, as the blood diamonds help to destroy people living in the world. A character whose dying is only contributing to more death and therefor doesn't value "life".

So in this case for this character the double meaning is on what we truly value and dark ironies of the use of "blood" here.

Answer (score 0):

I think Darth's answer is on the right track, but takes a roundabout way to get there.

Blood diamonds are associated with misery and death.  If you've ever known anyone with HIV or seen documentaries on it, it's a miserable disease that leads to death.  I can definitely see the parallel between the two.

Or, as M.A.R. said in their comment, it might just be a smartass reddit comment and we're looking too hard to squeeze a square peg into a round hole.